Decode OnLogs Data
I would like know if there is a way to decode data received at "OnLogs" callback.
I saw this issue : https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/issues/2841
However, it seems closed and there is no answer sadly.
I tried below code part, but no help.
logs.forEach((log)=>{
let type = web3.SYSTEM_INSTRUCTION_LAYOUTS.Transfer;
let data = type.layout.decode(log);
console.log(data);
})
How can I find the transfered token amounts without calling getParsedTransactions ?

Unfortunately, what you're trying to achieve is not possible using the logsSubscribe RPC method. This method only streams the signature and the logs of the transactions.
The transfer amount is embedded within the transaction data itself, which isn't included in the data returned by the logsSubscribe method.
It’s possible that the program you're trying to index does log the transfer amount, but this is not common.
